# Perl Exec/System passing parameter

Tags: perl, exec

I have an issue with the perl (v5.26.3) commands system or exec (both have the same behaviour)

Both command work fine

```
system ('git','pull','-ff','--no-rebase');
system ('git submodule --quiet foreach --recursive "echo \${name}"');
```

But when I split the "git submodule" into the arguments:

```
system ('git','submodule','--quiet foreach','--recursive "echo \${name}"');
```

Perl returns:

```
usage: git submodule [--quiet] [--cached]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] (--all| [--] <path>...)
   or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--checkout|--merge|--rebase] [--[no-]recommend-shallow] [--reference <repository>] [--recursive] [--[no-]single-branch] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] set-branch (--default|--branch <branch>) [--] <path>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] set-url [--] <path> <newurl>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] absorbgitdirs [--] [<path>...]
```

How can I pass the arguments?

Comment: Can you try split `'--quiet foreach'` into two arguments, like this `'--quiet', 'foreach'`

Comment: And split the `'--recursive "echo ..."'`  into two.  The whole command need be split into _words_ (or what's under `"...").

Comment: Instead of performing strange shell commands from inside Perl, why not look for a module that can do the work for you? One casual search on google turned up https://metacpan.org/pod/Git

Comment: Also, that is not what Perl returns, that is what git returns. It is printed to the terminal, which is the only reason you can see it. Another big flaw of using shell commands.

Comment: I seriously doubt `'... "echo \${name}"'` "works fine".

Comment: What is that `$name` -- which 'part' does it come from?  Not Perl. Not shell I presume. Is it some git's thing?

Comment: Thx, the split work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) invocation that takes a list we need to pass it the command broken into *words*

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the program given by the first element of the list with **arguments given by the rest of the list**. If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is `/bin/sh -c` on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms). If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is **split into words** and passed directly to `execvp`, ...

(my emphasis) <sup>†</sup>

Let's look at a trivial example.  Take a command like

```
ls -l --sort size dir "dir A"
```

and break it up, so to pass a list of "arguments" to the "command." There is no command `ls -l` but there is `ls` and its argument `-l`.  There is also no argument `--sort size`; there is `--sort` argument, and (its value) `size`. But stuff protected by quotes, like `"dir A"`, need be passed as such, as one "token."  So: `('ls', '-l', '--sort', 'size', 'dir', 'dir A')`

Same with `'--quiet foreach'` -- what argument is *that*, says `git`?

So, not knowing that `git` command, I'd go with

```
system('git', 'submodule', '--quiet', 'foreach', '--recursive', '"echo \${name}"');
```

I am leaving that `"echo \${name}"` exactly as it is since I don't know what it means.  But that may well need be written differently, please clarify.<sup>‡</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> See `man 3 exec`.

But it is also instructive, and perhaps more easily understood, to see how the shell (bash) does this, once it [parses](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) a line given to it.  It is the "Step 6" on the linked wiki page, where the command is finally prepared to be passed to the program.

---

<sup>‡</sup> Coming to think about it -- thanks to `ikegami` for a comment -- it is unclear, while it sure matters, what that presumed `$name`  variable is and ... who it belongs to.  Does it need to be extrapolated at some stage, or is it a `git` thing that need be passed to `git` as is?

This does not affect the overall point of this answer: to break the command into *words* to pass to `system`'s invocation with LIST.  That means essentially to break it by space, except for parts where space is escaped (like it effectively is by quotes).

(Also see the [exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec) page, at least for how to use LIST invocation in a case when there's only one argument but we still want to avoid the shell.)

Comment: `'"echo \${name}"'` is going to even more broken than it was before now that the shell is no longer invoked. I should probably be just `$name`.

Comment: @ikegami Good point, I didn't think of what that `$name` is.  Need clarification for that.  Added a comment for now...

Comment: Thx, with the additional split works